# How can I scrape through the Microsoft CVE Webpage that assigns its content dynamically (preferably using Python)?

Tags: python, security, web-scraping, web-crawler

The concerned page is https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-US/security-guidance/advisory/CVE-2018-8176

On viewing the page source, I do not get any relevant info about the content of the rendered page. How can I scrape the content available in the description ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the requests made by the page you linked using the "Network" tab of the Chrome developer tools with the "XHR" filter, and it looks like the page queries the vulnerability information from an API. You can inspect what this API returns using `curl` (with some prettyfication):

```
curl https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/api/security-guidance/en-US/CVE/CVE-2018-8176 | python -m json.tool
```

Coming back to your Python code, you don't need to scrape the content of the page you linked, and can just query the API provided by Microsoft directly:

```
import requests

cve_url = "https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/api/security-guidance/en-US/CVE/CVE-2018-8176"

response = requests.get(cve_url)
cve_dict = response.json()

print(cve_dict["cveTitle"]) # prints: Microsoft PowerPoint Remote Code Execution Vulnerability
print(cve_dict["description"]) # prints: <p>A remote code execution vulnerability...
```

Comment: Looks like `https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/api/security-guidance/en-US/CVE/CVE-2018-8176` is not working. Its returning default HTML page and not the actual content. It was working till last month. I have asked a new question about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67641428