# Python Error while Scraping Microsoft CVE Webpage

Tags: python, security, web-scraping, web-crawler

So, I read the question below. The answer provides some codes for further testing.

[How can I scrape through the Microsoft CVE Webpage that assigns its content dynamically (preferably using Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50446485/how-can-i-scrape-through-the-microsoft-cve-webpage-that-assigns-its-content-dyna)

Looks like

https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/api/security-guidance/en-US/CVE/CVE-2018-8176

is not working. Its returning default HTML page and not the actual content. It was working till last month. And was returning JSON data
can someone please help me finding new URL which can returns proper json data.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the Json with CVE data with this example:

```py
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = (
    "https://api.msrc.microsoft.com/sug/v2.0/en-US/vulnerability/CVE-2018-8176"
)

data = requests.get(url).json()

# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print(data["cveTitle"])
print(BeautifulSoup(data["description"], "html.parser").get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
Microsoft PowerPoint Remote Code Execution Vulnerability
A remote code execution vulnerability exists in Microsoft PowerPoint software when the software fails to properly validate XML content. An attacker who successfully exploited the vulnerability could run arbitrary code in the context of the current user. If the current user is logged on with administrative user rights, an attacker could take control of the affected system. An attacker could then install programs; view, change, or delete data; or create new accounts with full user rights. Users whose accounts are configured to have fewer user rights on the system could be less impacted than users who operate with administrative user rights.Exploitation of the vulnerability requires that a user open a specially crafted file with an affected version of Microsoft Office PowerPoint software. In an email attack scenario, an attacker could exploit the vulnerability by sending the specially crafted file to the user and convincing the user to open the file. In a web-based attack scenario, an attacker could host a website (or leverage a compromised website that accepts or hosts user-provided content) that contains a specially crafted file designed to exploit the vulnerability. An attacker would have no way to force users to visit the website. Instead, an attacker would have to convince users to click a link, typically by way of an enticement in an email or instant message, and then convince them to open the specially crafted file. After the file is open, the user would need to move their mouse over a specific location on the page within the PowerPoint file to trigger the vulnerability.Note that the Preview Pane is not an attack vector for this vulnerability. The security update addresses the vulnerability by correcting how Microsoft PowerPoint handles objects in memory.
```